# Canvas .drawImage() function doesn't draw the requested thumbnail of a video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a function where a certain time frame from a video will be displayed as an image. the function accept 2 inputs, namely the path to the video, and the **certain second**, where the time frame should be displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="imageDiv" width="350" height="200"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</div>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">

// src will be the path to the video
// sec will be the second we want to display from the video

function dispImg(src, sec) {

    var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    video.src = src;
    video.type = "video/mp4";
    video.currentTime = sec;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 350, 200);
    document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(canvas);
}

dispImg("sample.mp4", 10)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

from my current code, I expect the thumbnail displayed in the video section (id="myVideo") is also drawn in the div section (id="imageDiv"). unfortunately it's not the case, since its all white in the div section.

Is there any suggestion to my problem? thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probable that the video hasn't loaded far enough or hasn't finished seeking at the time you're calling `drawImage`.

If that is the cause, you could wait for an event to trigger, like this:

```
function dispImg(src, sec) {

    var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    video.src = src;
    video.type = "video/mp4";

    // For more events, see:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events
    video.addEventListener('seeked', (event) => {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 350, 200);
        document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(canvas);
    });
    // After creating the event handler, change the position of the video.
    video.currentTime = sec;
}
```

I think when you use the `seeked` event, you don't need to wait for events such as `canplaythrough`.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna see this example [JSFiddle Timeline by kmturley](https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/z99cmwtq/)

```js
function createImage() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    timeline.appendChild(canvas);
}
```